# Apache James 3 DataBase DataSource

Tags: database, apache, datasource, mail-server, james

How to configure the DataSource tag in the Spring-Server.xml ?
I have been trying to configure it, but actually i didn't find any useful reference about that :
i was writing it this how :

```
 <data-source class="org.apache.james.util.dbcp.JdbcDataSource" name="JamesDS">
 <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
 <dburl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:test</dburl>
 <user>James</user>
 <password>123456</password>
 </data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `dataSource` as a bean, each line you wrote inside should be defined as a `property`. An example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

As you can see from the example, you can use different drivers - depends on the DB you're connecting to.

Another example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

**IMPORTANT**:
from [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) about `DriverManagerDataSource`:

> This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool
>   Connections.  It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown
>   connection pool,  implementing the same standard interface, but
>   creating new Connections on every call.
>
> If you need a "real" connection pool outside of a J2EE container,
>   consider Apache's  Jakarta Commons DBCP or C3P0. Commons DBCP's
>   BasicDataSource and C3P0's  ComboPooledDataSource are full connection
>   pool beans, supporting the same basic  properties as this class plus
>   specific settings (such as minimal/maximal pool size etc).

I recommend on reading the following [good introduction to JDBC](http://www.java4s.com/spring/spring-jdbc-complete-introduction/)

Comment: Thank u for your reply! but I am still facing some problems while attempting to start the server(running run.bat)

An exception is being thrown java.lang.IllegalStateException : cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database] for property 'database'

This exception is thrown because i have written in the Spring-server.xml :

<property name="dataBase" value="Oracle"></property> under the id=vendorAdapter

What do you advice me to do to solve this error

Comment: Restarting the server (usually) has nothing to do with DB connection. You should be able to restart the server, and fail on a request to your application that requires DB connection.

Comment: Before editing the datasource configuration, the server starts normally without any exception, but when i configured it, i am sure that i have some mistakes in the configuration, would you please give me a complete sample a\concerning only the datasource block...
Thank a lot you in advance !!

Comment: @primeFaceUser I posted two examples using different drivers